# Stokes's Theorem: Show that the integral is independent from the surface

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stokes-theorem

Problem:

> Show that the value of $\Omega=\iint_{\Sigma}\dfrac{(a-x)dydz+(b-y)dzdx+(c-z)dxdy}{[(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2+(c-z)^2]^{3/2}}$ is independent of the choice of the surface $\Sigma$, provided its boundary $\Gamma$ is kept fixed.

First off, I have no idea how could two different surfaces have the same boundary. Any explanations, preferably with examples, are welcome.

Then, if I want to solve this problem using Stokes's Theorem, I should find a suitable normal vector and the curl of a vector function $F=(f,g,h)$. But all I've been doing are blindly taking stuff from the original integral to make up curl(F), but then I couldn't figure out what the regional function should be.

Using the divergence theorem, I was able to see that if $\Sigma$ is closed and we let F lie in $\Sigma$, the integral is 0. Other than that there's nothing I could think of. How do I prove this?

Comment: Two hemispheres share the same boundary. The intuitive example is to think about blowing a bubble from a hoop. Each unique surface as the bubble grows and deforms still has the circular hoop as a boundary.

Comment: For instance, the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ for $0 \leq z < 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ for $z = 1$ and the elliptic paraboloid $z = 1 - x^2 + y^2$ for $0 \leq z \leq 1$ have the same boundary.

Comment: Finding the potential is unnecessary. Since you calculated that the divergence is zero, we know that it is a curl thus $$\iint_{\Sigma_1} \operatorname{curl}F = \int_\Gamma F = \iint_{\Sigma_2} \operatorname{curl}F$$ where $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ share the same boundary.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Could you explain the equation you wrote more? Also the problem didn't require $\sigma$ to be closed but when I used the divergence theorem I added that requirement.

Comment: The equation is Stokes' theorem twice

Comment: @NinadMunshi Doesn't the formula of Stokes' theorem contain the normal vector? How did you pick that vector in your equation?